# Trouble with URL format in HTML form

Tags: html, forms

I'm clearly missing something super-obvious but please take pity on me; I'm new at this.

I'm trying to create a form that will open a URL with this format:

`http://searchplace.com/?sid=Do:Re&id=Fa:(8 digit number input into form)`

This is what the form looks like now:

```
<form method="get" action="http:/searchplace.com/" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="Do:Re">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="Fa:">
    <input type="text"  name="q" maxlength="8" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 

</form>
```

There are at least two problems here:

1) The colons (between Do and Re in the first input and after Fa in the second input) get changed to %3A. I've tried with and without the `enctype`, and I've tried saying `value="Do&#58;Fa"` instead of `value="Do:Fa"`. I even did some messing around with `accept-charset="utf-8"` which I now suspect was a red herring. I just want a colon! (Well, two colons, obviously.)

2) Right now, the last bit of my form returns something like `Fa%3A&q=12345678`. Obviously the q is because I gave the text input the name "q." But I don't want the q, I just want an unbroken `Fa:12345678` and I can't figure out how to append the input number onto the end of the URL without giving it a name.

Hopefully I am not so far off that my question makes no sense at all. I've actually solved the original problem that led me to try to create this form but the actual form itself is still driving me crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want, but you shouldn't approach it that way.
You must use diffrent split functions to extract the data.
I suggest using

`<input type="text" name="fa_q" maxlength="8" value="" />`

and then you would get url like id=fa&fa_q=12345678, and you know you can assign "fa" to "fa_q".

Also the %3A is the browser url encoding, you can get rid of that by applying function `urldecode` in PHP

If you're stubbord, and still want it like this fa:12345678 the url should look like

`/?q=fa:12345678`

You must get rid of all input names and put ID's instead, and must apply the value to input with the name "q" by using javascript. You would need regular expressions thou.